# RegExp add something before closing bracket

Tags: php, regex

Say I have the following string..

```
.hello {
  color: blue;
  width: 200px;
}

.world {
  color: red;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Using RegExp() in php is it possible to add a string before the closing bracket for `.hello`?

For example:

```
.hello {
  color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  added string here
}
```

Comment: `(\.hello[^}])+}`

Comment: I don't think `RegExp()` is a native php function. So you will either need to post that function or explain further.

Comment: If the opening and closing braces are at the start of the string, try `^(\.hello\s*{(?:\n.*)*?\n)}` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lDkzVQ/1) using [php](https://3v4l.org/clrlo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
$str = ".hello {
  color: blue;
  width: 200px;  
}";


$new_str = preg_replace('~(\.hello[^\}]+)}~','$1HAHAHAHAHAH;}',$str);

print_r($new_str);
```

Output:

```
.hello { color: blue; width: 200px; HAHAHAHAHAH;}
```